# HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject not exist in Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resources, httpcontext

I'm writing various class libraries (tools and helpers) for my future ASP.Net project.

Right now my solution doesn't have web project, but it's not supposed to be a problem.
I added reference to System.Web to project and now I able to access HttpContext in code.

Below my code for resource manager class that suppose to get application global resources:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace ResourceManager
{
    public class ResourceManager : IResourceManager
    {
        HttpContext context;

        public ResourceManager(HttpContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }

        public string GetError(string key)
        {
            return context.GetGlobalResourceObject("Errors", key).ToString();
        }

        //And so on........
    }
}
```

But unfortunately **Visual Studio** intellisense can't find **GetGlobalResourceObject**.

Hitting **F12**  and I can see this static function inside **HttpContext** class.

After running build I'm getting this error message:

**Member 'HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead**

It's strange behaviour and interesting for me why it's happening.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but from the error message I think the usage should be as below.

Essentially you just use the static `HttpContext` rather than creating an instance of it.

```
using System.Web;

namespace ResourceManager
{
    public class ResourceManager : IResourceManager
    {
        public string GetError(string key)
        {
            return HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Errors", key).ToString();
        }

        //And so on........
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not in web project, so I can't reference to HttpContext without getting it from outside. It's a class library project that don'k know anything about ASP.Net app.

Comment: But you have a reference to System.Web so you should still be able to use the static HttpContext like the error message is instructing you to do.

Comment: It not works. Try to copy my code into new Class Library project and try to build...

Comment: I have just created a new class library project and pasted the code above in.  Once I added the reference to `System.Web` it built with no issues.  What error are you getting when you try to build?

Comment: The screenshot shows you have not used the code from my answer, which is why you still have build errors.

Comment: Worked. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Great,  Please mark this as the answer if it helped resolve your issue.